# Наследование одноимённых интерфейсов из разных namespace-ов

Tags: c++, ооп

Вопрос чисто теоретический. Есть класс A, он наследуется от разных интерфейсов, имеющих одно и то же имя, но находящихся в разных пространствах имен.

```
class A : public Iface, public SomeoneNamespace::Iface
{
   // override pure virtual functions
};
```

Не компилируется, IntelliSense говорит мне, что я не переопределил чисто виртуальные функции интерфейса из пространства имен SomeoneNamespace.

Собственно, вопрос: допустимы ли одинаковые имена интерфейсов

Comment: а Iface и Iface из SomeoneNamespace одинаковы, или имеют идентичные методы  или поля?

Comment: Нет, каждый из них предоставляет лишь по два метода на чтение/запись, и ни одно из имен не повторяется.

Comment: вопрос об одинаковых именах интерфейсов? Eсли да, то я ради интереса собрал твой код - все отлично собирается (`VS 2015`)

Comment: @Duracell, спасибо, друг. Все утверждают, что это совсем не причина. Видимо, что-то косвенно влияет. Как разберусь, обязательно отпишусь, в чем дело.

Comment: Нужен [mcve]. Да и `IntelliSense` это ещё до стадии компиляции.

Comment: кстати да, аналогично в (VS2012) всё изумительно собралось, если что [тут код](http://pastebin.com/6fwMaxYy).

Comment: @alexolut, повторюсь, вопрос - чисто теоретический.

Comment: @isnullxbh Вы же пишете, что "не компилируется", значит есть код. Но Вы его не предоставили в достаточном объеме.

Comment: К сожалению, это невозможно, так как он закрыт. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, есть десятки классов, которые работают с этими интерфейсами, и, как, по-Вашему, я должен выделить "полезную" часть ? Поэтому я настаиваю на том, что вопрос - теоретический. Или с каких-то пор на StackOverflow нельзя задавать вопросы подобного характера ? Пруфы в студию, и я его удаляю. Нет - извольте не напоминать мне о "Минимальном, самодостаточном и воспроизводимый примере"

Comment: Я действительно не смогу показать какую-то часть кода, ибо у интерфейса много наследников. Как мне теперь кажется, возможно, я где-то допустил синтаксическую ошибку, и из-за нее весь сыр-бор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пространства имен (`namespace`) как раз вводились для того, чтобы избежать конфликтов имен. Если же в точке использования присутствует какая-либо неоднозначность (например из-за наличия нескольких `using namespace` ранее по коду) для любого имени (неважно имя это класса, переменной или функции), то компилятор недвусмысленно даст об этом знать сообщением вида:

> reference to 'Something' is ambiguous

В таком случае использование полностью квалифицированных имён вида `Namespace::Something` позволит избежать неоднозначности. А это значит, что уже совершенно не важно, когда в разных `namespace` присутствуют одинаковые имена.

---

> IntelliSense говорит мне, что я не переопределил чисто виртуальные функции

Ошибка отсутствия реализации чисто виртуальной функции возникает при попытке инстанцирования объекта абстрактного класса. При определении класса она возникать не может, т.о. наследование интерфейсов (с точки зрения языка) реализовано правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, это полезная информация !

Answer (score 1):

Да, если эти интерфейсы из разных пространств имён, а так же нет одинаковых составляющих интерфейсов (если есть, то наследуйте с `virtual`).

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, о каких одинаковых составляющих интерфейсов идет речь. И как это разрешается с помощью `virtual`.